# ruby on rails filtering inside an association

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have `scaffold student name:string is_active:boolean` and `scaffold attendance student_id:integer event_id:integer`

```
Student has_many :attendances

Attendance belongs_to :student
```

Attendances/_form.html.haml:

```
= simple_form_for(@attendance) do |f|
  = f.error_notification

  .form-inputs
    = f.association :student
    = f.association :event

  .form-actions
    = f.button :submit
```

How to edit the association dropdown to see there only students that have `is_active : true`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to separate your logic from your views. So, in the controller method that uses the form above you can define what you want to see in your drop down menu:

```
def controller_method
  @active_students = Student.where(is_active: true)
end
```

and in your association in your form you can specify the drop down menu [collection](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) to be equal to `@active_students`:

```
f.association :student, collection: @active_students
```

Alternatively, in one line:

```
f.association :student, collection: Student.where(is_active: true)
```

Comment: I tried the second one. It works, but when I go to attendance/edit the student field is shown blank, if he is no longer active. Can this be solved?

Comment: Well if you only have one student in your database and he/she is not active then there will be nothing displayed in the drop down menu. What do you want to happen instead?

Comment: If for example I want to edit the `= f.association :event`, and the student is not active any more, it will show a blank    `= f.association :student`...

Comment: Correct. That is what you asked for. You may need to rethink about what you want your application to do. I will think about other approaches and get back to you.

Comment: I used students & events as a simplified example :)